# JavaScript, what is the fastest way to find n+ elements of array A in array B that are in the same order

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, compare, comparison

Two arrays, each contains 10 elements:

`A = [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}, {a:5}, {a:6}, {a:7}, {a:8}, {a:9}, {a:10}]`
`B = [{a:11}, {a:221}, {a:4}, {a:5}, {a:6}, {a:7}, {a:8}, {a:10}, {a:9}, {a:33}]`

What's the most efficient way to find **5+** elements of array **B** that are in array **A** and are in the same order?

Expected result:
`{a:4, match:true}, {a:5, match:true}, {a:6, match:true}, {a:7, match:true}, {a:8, match:true}`

Comment: what is your way?

Comment: Just so you're aware `A[3] === B[2] // false`

Comment: @evolutionxbox they are not equal, but I'm not sure what's your point...

Comment: So you're aware for when you are comparing values. It's a valid point

Comment: Do they need to be consecutive? I.e. in the above array, would the algorithm find 5 or 6 matching elements?

Comment: @Bergi - yes, they have to be consecutive, that's the point. So the algorithm would return only 5 elements - https://d.pr/i/yu8b3C

Comment: Then you're looking for a basic [substring search algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String-searching_algorithm). There are many, and their performance differs, is case-dependent, and complicated to calculate.

Comment: @Bergi how would you implement it?

Comment: Oh wait, no, you don't know beforehand *which* substring to search for. You're rather looking for something like the [(longest) common substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) between the two arrays. Have a look at [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/common-substrings) I just dug up and see how they implemented it (their algorithm is good)

Comment: @Bergi exactly. Algorithm should look for the first matching element, then check if the rest of elements are matching AND if they are in the same order. If one of the next elements doesn't match, then - IF(result < 5) the result should be ignored and search should reset, ELSE exit and that's the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220838/discussion-between-el-kopyto-and-bergi).

Answer (score 1):

This approach looks for same values for property `a` and assumes that only one subset of same ordered objects exists.

You could take two loops, one for storing all indices and a filter function which takes an index and checks it with the stored index.

```js
const
    a = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2 }, { a: 3 }, { a: 4 }, { a: 5 }, { a: 6 }, { a: 7 }, { a: 8 }, { a: 9 }, { a: 10 }],
    b = [{ a: 11 }, { a: 221 }, { a: 4 }, { a: 5 }, { a: 6 }, { a: 7 }, { a: 8 }, { a: 10 }, { a: 9 }, { a: 33 }],
    result = b.filter(
        ((indices, i, last) => ({ a }, j, { [j - 1]: { a: last } = {} }) => {
            if (!i && (a in indices)) return i = indices[a] + 1;
            if (indices[a] === i && indices[last] + 1 === i) return i++;
        })
        (Object.fromEntries(a.map(({ a }, i) => [a, i])), 0)
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Your solutions returns 6 elements, with the last one {a:10} which doesn't match. Only five elements should be returned by the algorithm: https://d.pr/i/yu8b3C

Comment: this is nice! How to mark the returned elements, i.e. match:true?

Comment: after filtering (just ietrate an update)? which array?

Comment: That would work, but I wonder if there is a way to mark the elements in the result without additional iteration, so the performance won't decrease.

Comment: this algorithm fails if i.e. first elements of both array are matching: a[0] = 1, b[0] = 1 - the result contains only the first element. How to improve this so that the algorithm returns the expected result (described in question)?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs it, this is what I came with. It's not perfect - in some cases when less than 5 elements matches and they are placed at the end of the A table, the result returns them. But in such cases the result can be ignored outside of the algorithm.

```js
const a = [{a:1}, {a:2}, {a:3}, {a:4}, {a:5}, {a:6}, {a:7}, {a:8}, {a:9}, {a:10}]
const b = [{a:11}, {a:221}, {a:4}, {a:5}, {a:6}, {a:7}, {a:8}, {a:10}, {a:9}, {a:33}]

    let j = 0;
    let firstIndex;
    let minMatch = 5

    while(j <= b.length && b.length) {
      if(j === 0) {
        firstIndex = a.map(({a}) => a).indexOf(b[j].a);
        if(firstIndex > -1) {
          j++
        } else {
          b.shift();
        }
      } else {
        if (b[j].a === a[j + firstIndex].a) {
          j++;
        } else {
          if (j < minMatch) {
            while(j > 0) {
              b.shift();
              j--;
            }
            firstIndex = a.map(({a}) => a).indexOf(b[j].a);
            if (firstIndex > -1) {
              j++
            }
          } else {
            while (b.length > j) {
              b.pop();
            }
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(b);
```